# Remove all Gearman jobs from the Gearman Job Server

Tags: php, unit-testing, gearman

Is there a way to remove all Gearman jobs from the Gearman Job Server? I have a PHP application that runs Gearman jobs in the background. For my unit tests I need to ensure that a) there are no jobs waiting for a worker that executes it and b) that there is no worker working. The latter is not that important because it is easy to kill the workers but the former--I don't know how to implement this.

Comment: We have already enough unemployment, thank you very much! `</mandatory lame german-gearman joke>`

Comment: Wouldnt it make more sense to mock the Gearman Service instead of relying on a real physical server running?

Comment: Yes I am also doing that. But beside the main application there are small scripts that are executed via HTTP that are very slim and didn't include anything. They only call the GearmanClient to run a job in the background and then they are gone. I am testing them with cURL.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

### Removing all jobs of single type

Use the following command (just replace `FUNCTION_NAME`):

```
gearman -n -w -f FUNCTION_NAME > /dev/null
```

To remove only `n` number of jobs add `-c n` param, i.e. to remove 20 jobs:

```
gearman -c 20 -n -w -f FUNCTION_NAME > /dev/null
```

### Removing all jobs from server

If you want to remove all jobs, run the following loop:

```
for MATCH in $(echo status | nc 127.0.0.1 4730 | grep -v \\. |  grep -Pv '^[^\t]+\t0\t' | cut -s -f 1-2 --output-delimiter=\,); 
do 
    gearman -n -w -f ${MATCH%\,*} -c ${MATCH#*\,} > /dev/null;
done
```

Replace `127.0.0.1 4730` with your gearmand server address and port.

> > ps: removing jobs from persistent storage (i.e. sqlite) will not remove them from gearmand until it is restarted (because gearmand process has in-memory cache)

Comment: Thank you. Is it also possible to remove all jobs (FUNCTION_NAME = *)?

Comment: Here you go. Added recipe to remove all jobs.

Comment: The shell script doesn't work for me. The second seams to filter out everything. But I do need this within php test cases and I will write a script there to get all jobs and to start some processes to eat up all those jobs. Thank you!

Comment: @ArturBodera is it possible to delete jobs from remote server? (to call gearman -n -w -f ${MATCH%\,*} -c ${MATCH#*\,} > /dev/null;) on other ip?

Comment: Sure, just use `-h` for remote host and `-p` for port. More [info in the docs](http://gearman.info/bin/gearman.html).

Answer (score 0):

Using Persisten Queues it's easy, just truncate the queue table.

Comment: How are the jobs stored by default? In the memory I think, right?

Comment: In memory, I think so. In an old school way, you can restart Gearman service. Googling, I can't found a better solution, also in Gearman website. What type of processes are you doing with gearman? Maybe you can implement persistent queues and work with them.

Comment: This won't work unless you restart gearmand after truncating the table